# ¿Cómo mandar parámetros en DOMPDF?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dompdf

Trato de mandar variables para poder usarlas en mis reportes, pero no logro hacerlo.

**Mi botón que manda la la variable:**

```
<a style="font-size:13px" class= "btn btn-dark icon-print" title="Imprimir" href="../Modelo/imprimir_reportes.php?num=<?php echo $ver[5] ?>"></a>
```

**Mi función PHP:**

```
<?php
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';  
    use Dompdf\Dompdf; 
    
    $param1 = $_GET['num'];

    $dompdf = new Dompdf();

    $html = file_get_contents("../Vista/pdfpruebacot.php?num=<?php echo $param1 ?>"); 
    
    $dompdf->set_option( 'dpi' , '120' );
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html); 
    $dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');
    
    $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
    $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
  
    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    $dompdf->render();

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento.pdf");
    echo $dompdf->output();

?>
```

**LO QUE ME SALE:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Al recibir con un GET y tratar de usarlo con echo, no me funciona

Comment: Acabo de darte una respuesta, ya nos diras si te ha funcionado. Por otra parte, veo que nunca has realizado el [tour] pues no te has ganado la medalla de **Informado** al hacerlo. Estaría bien que lo hicieras para aprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y para que tuvieras en cuenta la aceptación de las respuestas que te han sido útiles a tus preguntas, para así ayudar y colaborar con la comunidad mejor, no dejando preguntas eternamente sin respuesta válida y facilitando encontrar las respuestas útiles a los que vengan a ver tus preguntas. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

**Pude lograrlo, mandando el parametro directamente al archivo que sera el pdf.**

Lo mando asi:

```
<a style="font-size:13px" class= "btn btn-dark icon-print" title="Imprimir" href="../Vista/pdfpruebacot.php?num=<?php echo $ver[5] ?>"></a>
```

**Lo recupero así en pdfpruebacot.php:**

```
<?php 
 $cosa = $_GET['num'];
?>
```

**EJEMPLO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y esto esta en la parte de abajo de pdfpruebacot.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';  
use Dompdf\Dompdf; 

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$html = ob_get_clean();
//$html = file_get_contents("../Vista/pdfpruebacot.php?num=");

$dompdf->set_option( 'dpi' , '120' );
$dompdf->loadHtml($html); 
$dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');

$options = $dompdf->getOptions();
$options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

$dompdf->setOptions($options);
$dompdf->render();

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento.pdf");
echo $dompdf->output();
?>
```

> **OJO: No se si es lo optimo, pero me sirve para salir del paso.**

Comment: mmm... yo no veo que manejes el $_GET en esta solución... ¿como lo estas recuperando?  _¿Y si abres http://localhost/portallavemi/Vista/pdfpruebacot.php?num=006/2022 directamente te sale algo?_

Comment: Lo edito para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Vale, entendido, ahora si. Lo que no entiendo es que no te funcionaba mi solución, pues con el file_get_contents y pasándole correctamente el parámetro como exponia en ella, debería ser lo mismo, a menos que hubiera alguna cosa desconocida en ese pdfpruebacot.php que no devolviera nada en ese momento por lo que sea. Gracias por la explicación de todos modos, saludos!